# Should I put a comma here?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should I put a comma in the sentence after "mazes"? Does this comma change the meaning of the sentence?

1. A car could run and solve critical mazes using infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds were beyond my knowledge.
2. A car could run and solve critical **mazes, using** infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds were beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence seems to have two separate ideas: (1.) A car would run an solve critical mazes (2.) Using infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds were beyond my knowledge.

Are these ideas connected? Are they separate? Right now it's not clear what you mean, so your sentence is a little nonsensical. Unfortunately a comma won't help that.

Are you saying that you want to use a car to solve the critical mazes **because** using sensors and sounds are beyond your knowledge? If so, you should add a conjunction (like "because") to indicate the connection to your reader.

Are the ideas totally separate? Then they should be two separate sentences.

If you clarify the meaning more then I can give you better advice.

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1) A car could run using infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds +
2)  A car could solve critical mazes using infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds 

- these are two ideas. These were beyond my knowledge. 

Ideas are connected. Now Is it okay?

Comment: Based on my understanding of your response, I would rewrite your sentence to say "A car can solve critical mazes using infrared sensors and ultrasonic sounds, but these ideas are beyond my knowledge."

Comment: I think it loses the appeal I want to express.